# Retrieve multiple accounts from Microsoft CRM 2011 Online

Tags: java, dynamics-crm-2011

With Microsoft CRM 2011 online and using webservices,  I am using below method in my Main.java using the OrganizationServiceStub class created by webservices call. The output retrieved no of records is -1 can someone help where I am going wrong. I want to retrieve the accounts where name begins with "Tel" without giving the accountid. I can see the data exists in CRM.
Thanks

```
public static void getAccountDetails(OrganizationServiceStub service, ArrayOfstring fields)
{
    try{
    ArrayOfanyType aa = new ArrayOfanyType();   
    aa.setAnyType(new String[] {"Tel"});

    ConditionExpression condition1 = new ConditionExpression();
    condition1.setAttributeName("name");


    condition1.setOperator(ConditionOperator.BeginsWith);
    condition1.setValues(aa);

    ArrayOfConditionExpression ss = new ArrayOfConditionExpression();
    ss.setConditionExpression(new ConditionExpression[] {condition1});

    FilterExpression filter1 = new FilterExpression();
    filter1.setConditions(ss);

    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
    query.setEntityName("account");

    ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet();
    cols.setColumns(fields);
    query.setColumnSet(cols);

    query.setCriteria(filter1);

    RetrieveMultiple ll = new RetrieveMultiple();
    ll.setQuery(query);

    RetrieveMultipleResponse result1 = service.retrieveMultiple(ll);

    EntityCollection accounts = result1.getRetrieveMultipleResult();

    System.out.println(accounts.getTotalRecordCount());        
} 
catch (IOrganizationService_RetrieveMultiple_OrganizationServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (RemoteException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Crm 2011 & Java, but I cant see anything anything obviously wrong with the query. If you remove the filter do you get any results returned?

Comment: Also, consider the execution account, does the user who is running the test have permissions in Crm?

Comment: If I pass the account id, then it returns the value and other details. I have tried all possible options. But every time I get it as -1 record counts. Yes the user is admin user, has all the rights. If I use the demo example, of create, retrieve, update and delete it works. But if I want to do the retrieve only it returns -1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how similar your `EntityCollection` object is to the .Net version in the SDK, however you need to specify `ReturnTotalRecordCount` in the query's PagingInfo in .Net for the `TotalRecordCount` property to have a value. Could you not instead check `accounts.Entities.Count`?

Note: I'm not a Java guy either...

Answer (score 3):

For Java, include this code snippet works for the above issue

```
ArrayOfanyType aa = new ArrayOfanyType();   
aa.setAnyType(new String[] {"555"});
ConditionExpression condition1 = new ConditionExpression();

condition1.setAttributeName("telephone1");

condition1.setOperator(ConditionOperator.BeginsWith);
condition1.setValues(aa);

ArrayOfConditionExpression ss = new ArrayOfConditionExpression();
ss.setConditionExpression(new ConditionExpression[] {condition1});

FilterExpression filter1 = new FilterExpression();
filter1.setConditions(ss);

QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
query.setEntityName("account");

PagingInfo pagingInfo = new PagingInfo();
pagingInfo.setReturnTotalRecordCount(true);

query.setPageInfo(pagingInfo);

OrganizationServiceStub.ColumnSet colSet = new OrganizationServiceStub.ColumnSet();
OrganizationServiceStub.ArrayOfstring cols = new OrganizationServiceStub.ArrayOfstring();

cols.setString(new String[]{"name", "telephone1", "address1_city"});

colSet.setColumns(cols);

query.setColumnSet(colSet);
query.setCriteria(filter1);

RetrieveMultiple ll = new RetrieveMultiple();
ll.setQuery(query);

OrganizationServiceStub.RetrieveMultipleResponse response = serviceStub.retrieveMultiple(ll);
EntityCollection result = response.getRetrieveMultipleResult();
ArrayOfEntity attributes = result.getEntities();

Entity[] keyValuePairs = attributes.getEntity();

for (int i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i++) {
    OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType[] keyValuePairss = keyValuePairs[i].getAttributes().getKeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
    for (int j = 0; j < keyValuePairss.length; j++) {
         System.out.print(keyValuePairss[j].getKey() + ": ");
         System.out.println(keyValuePairss[j].getValue());
    }
}
```